# Python:Get value of a dictionary present in aTuple

Tags: python

I have a tuple like:  `t= ({'count': 5L},)`

Here i don't want to use for loop but want to get value as 5.Then how can i do it?

I tried with coverting to string then using JSON.

```
import json
s = str(t)
d = json.loads(s)
```

I got error:ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

And winded up with no result.

I want to get the value of count as integer 5 & store in a variable.

Anyone having any idea?

Comment: what is the output that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use Json since it is already your tuple is already a Python data structure.

If you know the index of the item in the tuple, and you know the keyname you can access it directly using:

```
t = ({'count': 5L},)
value = int(t[0]['count'])
```